Abort a Promise running in a call to puppeteer page.evaluate()
In puppeteer, I can abort various operations with an abort signal. For example, I can abort an HTTP request and a .waitForSelector().
I realize that page.evaluate() returns a value, not a Promise. I don't need to abort page.evaluate(). I want to be able to abort a promise inside page.evaluate() based on what happens in the rest of my code. For example, in this instance I want to race all of these against each other: a .waitForSelector, a .waitForNavigation, and a jQuery event I'm listening for on the browser page. I also need to remove the event listener, but I hope I can do that when I abort.
A timeout isn't good enough here because it doesn't let my program exit appropriately if the program needs to and it doesn't correctly let my test suite continue to the next test if needed. From what I can tell, a try/catch waits just as long.

page.evaluate() returns a promise that resolves to a serializable value. What you're asking for is entirely possible, but we'll need to see more context and code to help. Please show your code. Thanks.

Thanks for clearing that up. I misunderstood something I read. Showing some code might have helped, but there was so much wrong with it that it might have been distracting. Still, getting it ready to put in here might have helped with other problems I was having.

The solution I came up with sets up an abortable promise in the browser using variables that get put on window. Later when I need to clean up I use those window variables to abort the promise and remove the event listener.
One thing that's important is that the things that happen in regular node (outside of page.evaluate) are completely separate from the things that happen in page.evaluate. There's a puppeteer method called waitForFunction which might or might not help, but I'm not sure how to use that yet.
That is why I create a different abort controller for the waiting I do outside of page.evaluate.
I haven't solved everything. I explained in the comments.
function getEventPromise() {
  /** Wait for an event on the browser. */
  const jQueryEventPromise = page.evaluate(() => {
    // add window variables to use later
    // the abort controller for the browser
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const signal = controller.signal
    // abortable promise that adds a one-time event listener
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // aborting in here will clean up the page.evaluate too
      // if the signal is already aborted, just throw an error
      if (signal.aborted) {
        reject(signal.reason)
      }
      // prepare to throw an error later if the browser code aborts
      signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
        reject(signal.reason)
      })
      // otherwise, this handle should get called and resolve the promise
      function handler(event) {
        resolve("the event happened")
      }
      $(document).on("event", handler)
    })
    .then((returnedValue) => {console.log(returnedValue)})
    .catch((error) => {console.log(error.name)})
  })

  return jQueryEventPromise
}

// the abort controller for node
const controller = new AbortController()
const signal = controller.signal
// prepare the promises - they'll be waiting to detect what happens
const elementPromise = page.waitForSelector("#the-id", {visible: true, signal})
// other promises
// I haven't solved how to use waitForNavigation in here. I think it doesn't use an abort signal.

// do something, like clicking an element
const clickPromise = element.click()

// When I include clickPromise my race times out. I'm not sure why yet.
await Promise.race([
  Promise.all([/*clickPromise,*/ elementPromise]),
  Promise.all([/*clickPromise,*/ getEventPromise()])
])

// cancel the things that didn't happen
// abort the node promises
controller.abort()
// remove the event listener and abort the browser promise
await page.evaluate(() => {
  $(document).off("event")
  controller.abort()
})

// do other things

In actual code you would want to be more careful about what variables you put on the window because if you do this multiple times at the same time you could override the variables. You'd want something like window[uniqueName].controller = new AbortController().
You would also want to use that in your jQuery event to give the event a category, like "click.validator" in the examples on jQuery's docs. That is, $(document).off("event") would be $(document).off(`event.${uniqueName}`) and $(document).on("event", handler) would be $(document).on(`event.${uniqueName}`, handler). Maybe there's another way to handle that part, but I haven't figured out a way to pass just an event and a handler without also passing a selector, which I don't want here.
I have other problems in my actual code.
Like I said in the comments, waitForNavigation seems like it might not use signal because its console logs fire in the middle of other much later console logs. You can't abort a promise once it is made if it doesn't already accept aborting, so I'm not sure how to handle that.
Also like I said in the comments, I can't seem to put the click promise in the races. When I try my code times out.
My actual code is more complicated, though, so I need to troubleshoot with a simpler example.

They just added aborting for waitForNavigation a few days ago, so that should solve that problem: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/CHANGELOG.md#22150-2024-07-31
